# What is the meaning of the term "archives" in apt? Why would apt download "archives"?

Tags: apt, upgrade, archive

Why would `apt` try to download archives from `archive.ubuntu.com`?

```
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-58 linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-58-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-58-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-qt
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny xxd
9 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
9 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 124 MB of archives.
After this operation, 585 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

The above output says that `apt` *"Need to get 124 MB of archives"*.

What does the use of the term "archives" mean in this context?

Comment: Are you confused/concerned about the use of the term 'archive'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term 'archive' in a Debian-based system (like Ubuntu) typically refers to deb packages or to the repository providing those deb packages.

```
Need to get 124 MB of archives.
```

In this particular usage, the term `archives` means 'deb packages'